# Hang in pthread_join when try to debug with gdb in Emacs

Tags: c++, multithreading, emacs, gdb, freeze

I use gdb in Emacs and attach gdb to one thread of my application who has two threads. But when continue in gdb, the attached thread hang in pthread_join. And strange that if I use gdb NOT in Emacs, and do the same thing, the thread will not hang. 
It seems something wrong due to Emacs. How to fix this issue? 
Thanks.

Comment: I also use Emacs + gdb + threads, but have not experience this hang.  Perhaps you could show an [MCVE] ?

Comment: One possibility is that the thread is actually just waiting in `pthread_join` and you just need to switch threads in gdb (`thread 2` or something) and see what is happening there.